Semi algebraic sets and smooth manifolds
I would like to prove a result that I cannot see why it could be wrong in order to fix the idea.
Here is the result :

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a semi algebraic set which is a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $d$. Then the semi algebraic dimension of $A$ is $d$.

The attempt of proof :
We fix $x\in A$ and consider the tangent space $T_{x}(A)$ which is a vector subspace of dimension $d$. We first observe that a natural link between $A$ and $T_{x}(A)$ can be made through the orthogonal projection from $A$ to $T_{x}(A)$ is a semi algebraic map since
$$
P_{T_{x}(A)}(y) = \sum_{k=1}^{d}\langle y, e_k\rangle e_k
$$
And the set $T_{x}(A)$ being a vector subspace of dimension $d$ is a semi algebraic set. Thus the graph of $P_{T_{x}(A)}$ is given by a first order formula.
From this, I think that I should try to explore some property of the projection to establish a link between the dimension (as a vector space) of $T_{x}(A)$ and the semi algebraic dimension of $A$ but I do not see how to proceed.
If you have some hints please do not hesitate. In the case where the result I am trying to prove is false I would like to see a counter example if it is something you can propose.
Thank you a lot
